# Are these vectors co-planar?

Tags: geometry

I report you the question I was asked:

let $\underline{v}, \underline{w}, \underline{t} $ be three coplanar vectors, then $\{\underline{v}+\underline{w}+\underline{t}, 5\underline{v} + 7\underline{w} + \underline{t}, 12\underline{v} + 78\underline{w}+13\underline{t}\}:$

$ \circ  \text{ Are parallel}; \\ \circ  \text{ Are coplanar};  \\ \circ  \text{ Are not coplanar}; \\ \circ  \text{ Their triple product doesn't equal zero};  \\ \circ  \text{ None of the previous}; $

This was my attempt:

There are two chances:

- 1 vector is linearly independent, the remaining ones are its linear combination;
- 2 vectors are linearly independent. The remaining one is their linear combination;

Let's suppose for instance that $\underline{v}$ is the only one linearly independent. If that's not the case you can still exchange them to get to this situation, for evaluating case 1.

Then you can write $\underline{w}$ and $\underline{t}$ as its linear combination. For instance, $\underline{w} = \lambda\underline{v}$  and $\underline{t} = \mu\underline{v}$

Then you can re-write the previous one as follows:

$\underline{v}+\underline{w}+\underline{t} = \underline{v}+\lambda\underline{v}+\mu\underline{v} = (1+\lambda+\mu)\underline{v}$

$5\underline{v} + 7\underline{w} + \underline{t} = 5\underline{v} + 7\lambda\underline{v} + \mu\underline{v} = (5+7\lambda+\mu)\underline{v}$

$12\underline{v} + 78\underline{w}+13\underline{t} = 12\underline{v} + 78\lambda\underline{v}+13\mu\underline{v} = (12+78\lambda+13\mu)\underline{v}$

All of them are parrallel to $\underline{v}$

For the second frame: let's suppose now that two vectors are linearly independent: for instance let them be $\underline{v}$ and $\underline{w}$. If that's not the case you can switch them to make it so. This means that $\underline{t} = \lambda\underline{v}+\mu\underline{w}$ for some $\lambda, \mu$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Then you have that

$\underline{v}+\underline{w}+\underline{t} = \underline{v}+\underline{w}+(\lambda\underline{v}+\mu\underline{w}) = (1+\lambda)\underline{v} + (1+\mu)\underline{w}$

$5\underline{v} + 7\underline{w} + \underline{t} = 5\underline{v} + 7\underline{w} + (\lambda\underline{v}+\mu\underline{w}) = (5+\lambda)\underline{v} + (7+\mu)\underline{w}$

$12\underline{v} + 78\underline{w}+13\underline{t} = 12\underline{v} + 78\lambda\underline{v}+13(\lambda\underline{v}+\mu\underline{w}) = (12+13\lambda)\underline{v} + (78+13\mu)\underline{w}$

And they're coplanar. The case in which none of them is linearly independent is "silly", in fact their triple product would be 0, as all of them would be the null vector, and therefore they'd be coplanar.
To me the correct one is the second one as more general. Am I doing it right? It seemed me too easy for being a question from a test, and our teacher is usually really bad with questions. Is there any cheat here or I did it fine?

Comment: To show that they are parallel it seems that you have assumed them parallel!

Comment: Your phrasing "suppose for instance that v is the only one linearly independent" is strange.  You cannot talk about a single vector being "independent".  You can only talk about a vector being "independent" of **other vectors**.

Comment: @user247327 by definition a vector is linearly independent if the only linear combination giving the null vector is the one in which every coefficient is 0. That happens considering a single vector, whenever this isn't the $\underline{0}$

Comment: @gimusi: I showed that supposing $\underline{w}$ and $\underline{t}$ parallel to $\underline{v}$, then the new vectors are parallel to $\underline{v}$

Comment: @Bafforasta Yes indeed in this case the are parallel and all their combination are parallel, but why did you assume that w and t are parallel to v? you could have 2 linearly independent vectors

Comment: @gimusi Just to make sure that my teacher did not trick me ahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINTS**

$ \circ  \text{ Are parallel}$?: only if v,w,t are parallel

$\\ \circ  \text{ Are coplanar}$?: Yes, since they are combination of coplanar vectors

$\\ \circ  \text{ Are not coplanar}$? No, see previous answer

$\\ \circ  \text{ Their triple product doesn't equal zero}$? No, since thy are coplanar triple product is zero

$\\ \circ  \text{ None of the previous}$?: No

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. All three new vectors are linear combination of v,w,and t so they are in the same plane as v,w,and t.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are clearly not parallel because one is not a multiple or the other.  As far as being "co-planar" or "not co-planar", you started by saying that u, v, and w are coplanar- any linear combination of u, v, and w must also be coplanar.

"Their triple product doesn't equal zero?  No"

Are you saying that triple product **is** zero?